# FloatingActionButton is not pushed upwards in CoordinatorLayout with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I'm working with RecyclerView and FloatingActionButton (FAB) in CoordinatorLayout. Before jumping into details, this is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

This layout has a list of items using RecyclerView and there is an FAB at the bottom. You can also see a text called 'Save' which is invisible at the start. Once RecyclerView has some items, it will be displayed. Everything works as intended. However, when the text 'Save' is shown, it is not pushing FAB upwards.

Here's the layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/layout_main_container">

      <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_custom_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/custom_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

              <com.custom.CustomRecycler
                android:id="@+id/custom_recycler"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

               <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_add"
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/list_custom_recycler"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/save"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:text="Save"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:visibility="visible"
                 />

       </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

What is it differently I'm doing which prevents FAB from being pushed upward when the text is shown?

Do I need a nested scroll view? Any thoughts?

Comment: try changing the `anchorGravity`

Comment: No luck with that one!